# Powerpoint/Excel VBA: Is there anyway to programmatically change the SELECTION SHOWN for native dropdowns like table border pen color/weight?

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, powerpoint, vba

I'm wondering if there's a way to programmatically using VBA to change the value of the **selection shown** in the native PowerPoint/Excel dropdown lists, e.g., draw table pen color, style, etc. See below picture for what I mean:

[image]

I know how to directly set the border color, etc. of selected table cells, but would like to be able to "retain" that setting in a visible way to the user programmatically. Therefore, once the macro is run that changes the "draw table pen color" to blue and the pen weight to say 3pt, the user will see the dropdown turn into blue and the pen weight set to 3pt, and any subsequent drawing he/she does (outside of the macro) will be in blue at 3pt weight since such a setting is retained by ppt/excel.

Perhaps there is a way to do this via commandbars? For example, I know you can programmatically simulate the execution of a native commandbar button with something like:

```
PowerPoint.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")
```

Does anyone know if this is possible? I'm guessing the answer is no, but would appreciate any tips.

Thanks!

Edit: to be fair the most relevant utility of this is probably limited to the draw borders dropdowns and not so much the font/numbers setting ones. I had included those just as other examples of dropdowns but guess what I'm asking is not really applicable to them.

Comment: For example in Excel, When you change the font of say Cell A1 via code to Arial and the cell is selected then the font in the commandbar will show `Arial` so I am not able to understand why do you want to directly manipulate the commandbar

Comment: You are definitely right--I amended my post with an edit and realize it's still confusing. Do you see the purpose of directly manipulating the commandbar for drawing tables though? Point here is you can ideally directly set the pen color/weight/style, and then call on native mso functions like "all borders" or "outside borders"  without the need to program more complex code to recreate the draw borders function from scratch.